# Android APP controls PC via USB????i

Tags: android, connection, usb

We have currently developed an Android application that controls a larger multimedia installation via UDP. Now the installation should run in an environment in which no WIFI is available! security!!!

Can I build any network connection via USB to the computer? In debugging mode I have a connection from Eclipse ... if someone could help me here ... I

regards

Answer (score 0):

adb is basically telnet to your device. (What eclipse uses)

So you can open and forward ports from your computer to your device.

[ADB](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#forwardports) docs might help. But they don't mention UDP. Might set you in the right direction hopefully.

Comment: when I put "adb forward tcp:6100 tcp:7100" into my terminal i got "device not found". is it possible to communicate to other apps on the windows system?

Comment: You have debug mode enabled on your device right? along with the USB drivers installed?

Comment: Well getting ADB working is out of scope, there are lots of things that can cause that. Once you can `adb devices` and see the list of online devices. `adb forward ...` should work